# Why are all my Metro applications in German? Can I change?

Tags: language, windows-8-preview

My Metro applications on the Windows 8 Consumer Preview are all German.

I've selected English (United States) and live in Belgium (and have selected that so), yet it somehow makes my Metro applications German while I didn't configure it at such. People in Belgium speak mainly Dutch and French, so German doesn't make sense at all.

So, how do I get these Metro applications to be English?

Comment: I am using the Brazil Portuguese (PT-BR ABNT) keyboard layout and some Metro Applications (Messaging, People and Mail) are in German too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, my custom keyboard lay-out was not English but Dutch. Apparently this causes the Metro applications to somehow default to German. I solved the problem by making sure that my custom keyboard lay-out adds an `English` entry under `Languages` in the `Control Panel`. Fixed!

Comment: Someone probably confused Dutch with Deutsch :P